# Is there a way to solve this limit?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

It is possible to solve this following sequence limit?

$$\mathrm{E} [Q_2]=\sum_{i=1}^{S} \lambda_i^2n(n-1)(1-\lambda_i)^{n-2} $$
$$\mathrm{E} [Q_1]=\sum_{i=1}^{S} \lambda_in(1-\lambda_i)^{n-1} $$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\mathrm{E} [Q_2]}{\mathrm{E} [Q_1]} $$
where for every natural number i: $0<\lambda_i<1$

Written in another way:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{S} \lambda_i^2n(n-1)(1-\lambda_i)^{n-2}}{\sum_{i=1}^{S} \lambda_in(1-\lambda_i)^{n-1}} $$

Comment: You need additional constraints for the limit to exist at all. For example, it clearly diverges when $\lambda_i = 1/2$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The sequence always diverges to $\ {+}\infty\ $.

If $\ m=\max_\limits{1\le i\le S}\big(1-\lambda_i\big)\ $, then
\begin{align}
\frac{\sum_\limits{i=1}^{S} \lambda_i^2n(n-1)(1-\lambda_i)^{n-2}}{\sum_\limits{i=1}^{S} \lambda_in(1-\lambda_i)^{n-1}}&=\frac{(n-1)\sum_\limits{i=1}^{S} \lambda_i^2(1-\lambda_i)^{n-2}}{\sum_\limits{i=1}^{S} \lambda_i(1-\lambda_i)^{n-1}}\\
&=\frac{(n-1)m\sum_\limits{i=1}^{S} \lambda_i^2\left(\frac{1-\lambda_i}{m}\right)^{n-2}}{\sum_\limits{i=1}^{S} \lambda_i\left(\frac{1-\lambda_i}{m}\right)^{n-1}}\ .
\end{align}
As $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $ the $\ i^\text{th}\ $ terms in the sums $\ \sum_\limits{i=1}^{S} \lambda_i^2\left(\frac{1-\lambda_i}{m}\right)^{n-2}\ $  and $\ \sum_\limits{i=1}^{S} \lambda_i\left(\frac{1-\lambda_i}{m}\right)^{n-1}\ $ converge to zero unless $\ 1-\lambda_i=m\ $, in which case they remain fixed at $\ (1-m)^2\ $ and $\ 1-m\ $, respectively. Therefore,
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{m\sum_\limits{i=1}^{S} \lambda_i^2\left(\frac{1-\lambda_i}{m}\right)^{n-2}}{\sum_\limits{i=1}^{S} \lambda_i\left(\frac{1-\lambda_i}{m}\right)^{n-1}}=m(1-m)>0\ ,
$$
and hence
$$
\frac{(n-1)m\sum_\limits{i=1}^{S} \lambda_i^2\left(\frac{1-\lambda_i}{m}\right)^{n-2}}{\sum_\limits{i=1}^{S} \lambda_i\left(\frac{1-\lambda_i}{m}\right)^{n-1}}\rightarrow\infty
$$
as $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $.